# the same idea of panic (on being chased)

Tags: grammar

> Yes, it's possible to say "He ran from the lion", but that doesn't give us **the same idea of panic (on being chased)** that running "away from the lion" does. "Away" suggests you're trying to put a lot of distance between yourself and the object you're running from.

[Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ran-away-from-the-lion.3991810/)

---

I'm not sure if "**(on being chased)**" adjectivally modifies "**the same idea of panic**" or just "**panic**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It modifies **panic.** The **idea** is that you would feel panic if a lion was chasing you.